# Is it possible to use cmake without any compiler

Tags: linux, windows, cmake

We have a project made of python scripts and home-made tools. We use cmake with custom targets to handle the application of the tools and python sripts and install resulting binary resources.

We use this under GNU/Linux and MS Windows. It works well but we don't want to force our users to install a compiler, like Visual Studio under Windows.

So, is it possible to install and run cmake without any compiler ? We can use ninja as the build system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

1. CMake's [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command takes a `NONE` parameter (no compiler/languages searched for or activated)

   ```
   project(MyProject NONE)
   ```
2. [CMake's `-P` script mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) if you want to take CMake as a cross-platform scripting environment

Comment: Thanks. I in the meantime found this same answer by changing my Google query to: "cmake no compiler". It directed me to question #12023879